# In [...]Reincarnated as a Slime, did Rimuru gain magicules/mana when he consumed Shizu, the Orc Lord, and/or Ifrit?

Tags: reincarnated-as-a-slime

Per another [thread on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TenseiSlime/comments/9wify2/is_rimuru_tempest_too_op/e9kx84e?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x), it's clear Rimuru got a lot of strength/mana from Veldora. First because Rimuru was named by Veldora and second because Rimuru gets ongoing strength from him.

How did the other characters' strength/magicules/mana effect Rimuru when he consumed them?